# Web Analytics collected data into Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have search for insights regarding this topic and found information regarding this collected information being available on IGO_ data extensions. The issue is that despite of the fact I see identified users on Web Analytics, none of the IGO_ DE's have data.

Additionally, I only can see IGO_ DE's at Root Level but if the data is collected at BU level how can we retrieve the same?

On the other hand I have read that we must enable the IGO_ and PI_ Data Extensions through Personalization Builder > Predictive Email > Status > Settings icon > Data Extension Settings but when I try to do that I need to provide one Catalog. Can anyone provide me one example of the same and how it relates with the tracking data collected?

**Update**

This is what I have on my current status page. I have Base Collect Tracking Codes and Sessions collected. Now I wanted to see that data on the IGO_ and PI_ DE's so I can create Contacts segmentation based on this data.
The first warning means that i have to create a New Einstein Recommendation so that the web collected data be present on the DE's?

[image]

Once again Many Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to provide you a sample of a catalogue, without knowing what type of content you serve. This can either be products or content (articles). It should be a pipe delimited file, that you either provide daily on an FTP folder, expose as a public URL or upload manually. There are multiple documentation pages about catalogue implementation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_catalog.htm&type=5).

My personal favourite of building a catalogue is using Streaming Updates. However this still requires an [initial manual upload](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_catalog_import.htm&type=5) of a catalogue file, so your fields can be mapped.

Using [Streaming Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_streaming_updates.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) allows you to refresh your catalogue by simply placing a JS snippet next to your regular collect code. This ensures all the pages visited are included in catalogue.

Please be aware, that only pages included in the catalogue will have visits reflected in IGO Data Extensions. Should collect code trigger on a page not in catalogue, you will see an error in the [log](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_validate_collect_code_implementation.htm&type=5).

Please read the links in the text, as they contain necessary additional information which will help you with your implementation.

Brgds 
Lukas

Comment: Hi @Lukas, the type of content will be to track page visits, articles, etc. So I think it will be the Content Catalog (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_catalog_field_definition.htm&type=5). So my collect script and my catalogue file should have at least the required fields present on the following page https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_catalog_field_definition.htm&type=5 right? I will try to achieve this and provide feedback. Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is indeed correct

Comment: Hi @Lukas, just one more doubt. We only have the IGO_ data extensions at root level but we are collecting tracking information at BU level. I don't see any BU field on IGO_ data extensions so how the data flows to the BU?

Comment: Hi Pedro. The collect code is BU specific. So the data collected by the script goes to the MID defined in this call: _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);     
You will need to have separate collect codes for each BU where you need the data. Otherwise, you can solve this with Query Activities and Shared DEs.

Comment: Hi @Lukas, I was able to create a content Catalog and on the Status I'm getting hits on the Base Collect Tracking Code and on Sessions. Nevertheless I'm not able yet to Enable Einstein Data Extensions. I have 4 warnings and one of them says "This feature requires existing Einstein data extensions. Confirmation is pending, check back shortly. Contact support if you continue to see this message." I don't know if I need to wait more time but meanwhile I have created a new case on support. Let's see their feedback. I don't know if you have any additional comment. Many thanks for your support.

Comment: If your tracking and catalogue are implemented correctly, this error should disappear within 24 hours. If you tomorrow are still seeing this error please reach out to Salesforce support.

Comment: Hi @Lukas, yes I'm waiting for feedback from support. Meanwhile I was trying to collect test data at Root Level, because at Root Level I have the Data Extensions available so I don't have the first warning that I described above but i have the other 3. I will put a print-screen of what i have on the status console creating a new answer, I think it is more easier to explain

Comment: Hi @Lukas, I have added information to my initial question. Thanks again for your support

Comment: Hi @PedroLopes - did the errors disappear, once you finalised the configuration?

Comment: Hi @Lukas, no yet. I had today a call with support that was not conclusive. They are saying that I need to have item field on my catalog to be able to activate the data extensions. Because I created a Content Catalog Type I did not include a field like that. I have change the catalog to have a dummy value on the new item field but since this morning that Import Catalog status remains on Import Queued without finalizing the same, so we were not able to complete the test. I will have a new call today. Let's see... Many Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hi @Lukas, The Einstein DE are enable  and now I have data on PI_CONTENT and PI_CONTENTATTRIBS (information submitted through Catalog), and on the IGO_PROFILES (two different users that I used on my test). But I don't have data on the PI_SESSIONS or PI_CONTENTVIEWS that are essential to know what Content was access by Contact and when. On the trackPageView information should i put only the ContentID or all the fields that I indicated on the Catalog? _etmc.push(["trackPageView", {"ContentID": "1", "Link": "http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/*****", "Availability": "Y", "Title": "Page1"}]);